# VB6 - How to get Filename in AsyncRead Downloading Method?

Tags: url, vb6, download, filenames, file-extension

I'm trying to download files which have no Normal [FILENAME].[EXTENSION] in URL, Using AsyncRead Downloading Method. There is no problem in Downloading process (It is Downloading file completely and save the file into Temp files). So i want to get Real Filename with Extension to save it to another place same as original file which is for downloading.
I can get file name while the URL is something like this:
`Http://Host.com/Path/MyDoc.txt` ( So i can get File name "MyDoc" and extension ".txt" easily because it specified at the URL )

But when downloading URL is something like this:

`Http://Host.com/Path/download.php?File=9`

 I can not get the **Real** File name and Extension. Is there any way to get them on URLs like this?

Note: There is no problem in Downloading Process and I can download both of above files Completely. I Just want to get Filename and Extension.

Comment: There is no file name (or extension) since the server is just streaming data to you, i.e. you never requested a static resource.  At most if you did this another way (MSXML.XMLHTTP) you might check the Content-Type header after your request completes, and from that you could hard-code or look up translation from the MIME type to an extension.  But there *is no file name*.  Webscraping is *bad*, m'kay?

Comment: @Bob77 : Ok, Whats your mean? i have to send GET HTTP Headers using Winsock to the link? then the server will send me back the HEADERS which i can get extension? Filename is not really important but i have to have Extension, what I have to do ?

Comment: AsyncRead does not give you access to the response headers, so you must use another way to make the request.  Use one that provides response headers such as the one I mentioned above.  Use the value of the Content-Type header to get the MIME type.  Translate that to an "extension" for use by your program.

Comment: @Bob77 : I got MIME using Inet. Thanks